# Amazon Simple Workflow - Choosing Worker From Same Activity Type Nodes Based on System Usage

Tags: amazon-swf

I have four servers which are classified under the same activity type.  All four servers are consistently polling from SWF.  I start one workflow and one of the nodes start a processing routine.  This routine will take an hour long and 80% of the CPU resources of the server.

How do I make sure that the next workflow I start does not utilize this same server?  And so on for the third and fourth workflows I start?  Is there any logic I can put in my decider to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better handled on the level of the activity worker. The basic idea is that after a poll returns an activity task the next poll is not issued until the task is completed. By monitoring the depth of the task list you can support autoscaling of worker nodes if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, are there any write-ups or video presentations of companies using this approach?

Comment: I'm not aware of any. But it is pretty straightforward to do (in Java) by using http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/worker/SynchronousActivityTaskPoller.html directly instead of WorklfowWorker.